# Joomla - HTML in registration fields

Tags: joomla, user-registration

The HTML-code in the description for a custom field, is shown in plain text and not shown as a link. I've tried changing filtering, updating templates, all plugins etc.

Anyone know how to change so the HTML gets converted to a link?

Here is the page: https://sommerwind.se/loggain?view=registration

Comment: Is this issue resolved?  I had a quick look and didn't see any plaintext links.  If you are no longer experiencing this issue, you can: post how you resolved it or remove your question.  I believe all questions should meet a clear resolution (Accepted Answer, Question Closure, or Page Deletion)  Abandoned question represent an information deadend for researchers (and that wastes time).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

Just copy the folder administrator/components/com_fields from a working site to the same folder on the failing site (so you overwrite the files)